# Set TextView text size to value stored in SharedPreferences. Use xml file for default values

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, android-xml

I want to make a simple thing: Retrieve a "fontSize" value from SharedPreferences and set the textSize property of a TextView to that value:

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChapterActivity.this.getBaseContext());
             float fontSize = preferences.getFloat("fontSize", R.integer.defaultFontSize);
             textView.setTextSize(fontSize);    
             Log.v("Debugging font size", "Text View font size " + textView.getTextSize());
         }
     });
```

In `preferences.getFloat(key, defValue);` I don't want `defValue` hard coded because I use that value in other code, so I use a xml resource file to retrieve that `defValue`, so I use:

```
float fontSize = preferences.getFloat("fontSize", R.integer.defaultFontSize);
```

The xml file for those default values is in the "values" folder and this is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="defaultFontSize">40</integer>
</resources>
```

When I run the code, there is not text in the text view and the output in LogCat is

```
10-09 09:27:56.332: V/Debugging font size(32341): Text View font size 1.5985213E9
```

If I replace R.integer.defaultFontSize for a hard coded value, for example, 40, the text appears in the text view and I get this output in LogCat:

```
10-09 09:39:18.072: V/Debugging font size(32509): Text View font size 30.0
```

So, what's happening here? Why the so high value in the first output?

Comment: why don't you try with float value in as default value. preferences.getFloat("fontSize", 40.0F);

Comment: @khurram No, I don't what hard coded values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.integer.defaultFontSize` is actually a constant generated by the SDK (the `aapt` tool). This constant *identify* your ressource and is internally used by the SDK (you should not this id by yourself).

To retrieve the value of a resource, you should use a "wrapper".

So, instead of :

```
float fontSize = preferences.getFloat("fontSize", R.integer.defaultFontSize);
```

you should use this :

```
float fontSize = preferences.getFloat("fontSize", myContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.defaultFontSize));
```

**Sources**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getInteger(int)

Answer (score 0):

try to access to your default value using

```
float defFloat = (float) aContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.defaultFontSize);
```

with your code you get the id of the resource not the value